# Install ios version later than 8 on mavericks

Tags: xcode

I'm on an old MBP that suffers greatly from any osx version beyond mavericks and I dont want to upgrade. I need to upgrade my ios simulator version beyond 8 though, is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is really a hardware question and belongs on SuperUser or Ask Different. You might ask yourself _why_ your MBP doesn't deal well with El Capitan or Sierra. There are ways to upgrade the hardware to make it very happy with those systems. But that is not an appropriate topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But your question isn’t about iOS. It is tangentially about Xcode which *could* make it on topic, since that is a programming tool, but what you are really asking is how to “fool” an installer to make it install something despite its pre-requisites. You are more likely to find some advice on this at Ask Different. I can suggest, however, that if your MBP struggles with a newer OS then it isn’t going to do well with Xcode 9. Some hardware upgrades, such as an SSD, may be the best answer.